# C++/MySQL, insert 200 datapoint array in 1 execute

Tags: c++, mysql, arrays, logging

I'm a newby regarding C++ and MySQL so if the answer is relativly simple I apologize in advanced, but I couldn't find any (working) solution so far although I know there must be.

I'm trying to log data from my sensor to an localhost MySQL database on the Raspberry. In order to maintain good performance several datapoints should be written to the SQL database in only one execute. At the moment i'm using this method for 50 signal points/second:

```
{
        i = 0;
        j = 1;
        k = 1;

        /* Creating pstmt statement*/
        pstmt = con->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO signal_" +day+ "_" +month+ "_" +year+ "(id, signal) VALUES (?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?)");

        /* Inserting 50 values */
        while (i < 50)
        {
            /* Insert ID integer (j = location, index[i]) */
            pstmt->setInt(j, index[i]);
            k = j + 1;

            /* Insert signal integer (k = location, signal[i]) */
            pstmt->setInt(k, signal[i]);
            j = j + 2;
            i++;
        }

        /* Execute pstmt using set values */
        pstmt->execute();
    }
```

*While the first array is being written to SQL the second array will fill up, then the second will be written to SQL and the first will be filled up again.

This example works for a single datapoint and an index but if I want to expand the data to 200 points/second and include an timestamp it will get very very messy.

So my question: Is there an easy way to insert the entire array into the MySQL database in 1 go? (The end-goal will be an array with 10 columns and 200 rows/second if the performance is good enough but at least 50/second)

Answer (score 1):

After proper research i found a way to insert an array into MySQL:

```
void log_the_data()

int i ;
string query, insert;
for (i=0 ; i < 50 ; i++)
{
    fprintf(f_log,"%ld %d %s %ld%s\n",nr_pts++,data[i],t_string,packet_counter,s_status);
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "(" << nr_pts << "," << data[i] << ",'" << t_string << "'),";
    insert = ss.str();
    query += insert;
}
query.erase (query.end()-1);

pstmt = con->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test(id, signal, time) VALUES " +query+ "");
pstmt->execute();
fflush(f_log) ;
clear_my_buffer() ;
```

This inserts 50 rows in 1 execute and can be easily expanded

Please correct me if this is not the proper way to do this